# How to list all possible routes in web.api host

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have to use a web.api host. Off course the spelling of the paths correctly is important, because if you make an error, you will soon end up with a 404 error.

Is there a way, a simple call, or maybe an application, that you can use to easily list all the possible paths in a web.api host?

I am looking for something similar like the list you get after specifying the correct .asmx file when adding a webservice to a Visual Studio project.

Comment: In addition: in a perfect world, the help section of the api host is properly filled with the info about the paths and responses, but in most cases this info remains empty...

Answer (score 1):

You can install `WebApiRouteDebugger` nuget package. There is a full totorial with how to on MSDN: [Debugging ASP.NET Web API with Route Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/04/04/debugging-asp-net-web-api-with-route-debugger.aspx)